# Hadoop: intervals and JOIN

Tags: java, join, hadoop, intervals

I'm very new to **Hadoop** and I'm currently trying to join two sources of data where the key is an **interval** (say [date-begin/date-end]). For example:

input1:

```
20091001-20091002    A
20091011-20091104    B
20080111-20091103    C
(...)
```

input2:

```
20090902-20091003    D
20081015-20091204    E
20040011-20050101    F
(...)
```

I'd like to find all the records where the key1 overlaps the key2. Is it possible with hadoop ? Where can I find an example of implementation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Pierre, not sure if you figured this out, but any idea's for this in Pig?

Comment: A solution was given on Biostar: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution was given on Biostar: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/8821

Answer (score 0):

I think all that's needed is a key class where hashCode() and equals() do what you want them to do. I suspect that you might encounter a problem where A overlaps B (i.e. A.equals(B) == true), B overlaps C, but C doesn't overlap A. If you implement such an equals() method, you'll probably get strange behaviour.

Basically, you want to do something like stabbing queries on a [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) (i.e. for all overlapping intervals E for an interval (p1.start, p1.end), perform stabbing queries for p1.start and p1.end).

But basically, no, I don't know a correct answer to your question. But maybe a query for ["Segment tree" hadoop](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Segment+tree%22+hadoop) will get you started.