# mapping mutation to a chromosome location with mapreduce/PIG or Disco

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-pig, bioinformatics, disco

**Goal:** To map mutation location from file1 to a region or feature from file two. For this you need to make sure that chromosome (chr1) and strands (+/-) are the same before comparing chromosome location from file 1 to regions of file2.

**Question**: How to use mapreduce or Disco to map one location to a region.. . Aka formulate the location -> chromosomal region in a mapreduce method?

**Description:** I have two medium sized files (10gb) and two file types that I wanted to process. I already have these files parsed in basic python but I will likely have to parse many larger similar files in the future so I wanted to try it with mapreduce (hadoop/Pig to be more specific)or Disco to learn .

While I can run the nodes on an EC2 cluster ideally a one cluster hadoop (yes I know it defeats the purpose) or on something like Disco or Sparc.

I like the idea of using Pig because that would reduce the process to just processing the file from .csv files but I have no idea for how to use mapreduce for mapping something to a region instead of just a key/value pair

Here is a visual representation of what I was thinking of: [image: was thinking of.]

File info:

1. First file is TCGA cancer SNP mutations. Some important features include

   - Chromosome location
   - Chromosome number
   - strand
   - sample id
   - the rest is not so important
2. 3' UTR sequence.

   - Chromosome start location: int
   - Chromosome end location: int
   - Chromosome number:  chrX
   - strand +/-
   - gene id
   - the rest is not so important

sample files are here:[two sample files](https://dfiles.eu/files/xo946pmij)

Finally python is my language of choice for this if it matters..

Comment: you should ask  http://www.biostars.org/ . See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832103

Comment: @pierre yeah i've seen some of the similar approaches. I'll ignore overlaps and missing ones for now.. I'm asking this in a more CS oriented manner then a bio specific parsing. I'd like to know how a software engineer would go about mapping this. I've added a link to a picture that hopefully shows what I'm trying to do.